# How to populate combo box from a select Query using VB in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm new to VB and trying to populate combo box in access from a select query's result which is getting value from another combo box and the code that i'm trying is:

```
Private Sub addPartsButtonForm_Click()

    ssql = "SELECT * FROM EquipmentTbl WHERE [EquipmentID] = '" & Me.equipmentCombo.Column(0) & "'"
    Me!comboParts = ssql

    Me.comboParts.Requery

End Sub
```

and when i press the button i got the following result in combo box:

```
SELECT * FROM EquipmentTbl WHERE [EquipmentID] = '34'
```

though its giving me the exact equipmentID but expected is something else other than that. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the combo RowSource. Also, no need for quotes in case field is Number.

```
Dim sSql As String
    sSql = "SELECT * FROM EquipmentTbl WHERE [EquipmentID] = " & Me.equipmentCombo.Column(0) 

     Me.comboParts.RowSource = ""
    Me.comboParts.RowSource = sSql
```

Comment: thanks for response sir....I'm now getting error of "data type mismatch in criteria. "any reason behind this? :(

Comment: thanks. So it was integer that's why i was getting error of type mismatch?

Comment: @MuhammadHamaadLatif    Yes, for Integer Long - no quotes, for string use '<string>' , for date use # date #